# Java browser that support applet

Tags: java, browser

Is there's any java embedded web browser(**free**) that support `applet running` ?

I don't mind if its use some native libraries.

Currently ,I already tried  `javafx web view` and `DJnativeswing`  and they dont detect java(doesn't support applet).

Comment: There was briefly a Sun Java browser product called the HotJava Bean. It disappeared in 1998.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the modern browsers (Chrome v42+, Firefox 64 for Windows, Microsoft Edge, etc) have dropped support for NPAPI which is required for applets to run. Oracle is recommending that developers switch over to Java Web Start instead of using applet as the technology is fading.  If you still need to use applets (eg. for school programming projects) you may need to uninstall your current browser(s) and install a legacy browser that still includes NPAPI.

Answer (score 0):

Browser do not support applets nativly. That's because applets need a java runtime environment and an browser adapter to display the content in the browser. But if you install a jre it always will install an plugin into you browser(s) if not already present.